# What motherboard should I get to upgrade my Cisco Ironport s360s motherboard

Tags: motherboard, server

I'm looking to update  my servers motherboard with a newer board. The reason I'm looking to upgrade is because I'd like to be able to install a decent graphics card. I can't at the moment because the PCI port is only a x4 and I would need a x16.

I'm not exactly sure what kind of motherboard is, but it's a Cisco Ironport s370. It used to be a network security server, but now it just sits in my basement with no use and I was going to try to upgrade it.

Price range, I could get anything up to $350 for a motherboard, and I already have a CPU, heatsink, and RAM that works with the server.

If you have any suggestions on what motherboard I should get, or if you can figure out what kind of motherboard it has please let me know.

**Update**

I opened it opened out found out some more specs.

It has 4x1GB of RAM

It has a Intel Xeon E5520

Comment: What CPU and RAM is it? I'm having a hard time finding specs about it besides [this document](https://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/docs/security/esa/hw/170Series_HW_Install.pdf) which just lists "1x2 (Dual Core)" and "4GB"

Comment: it has 4x1GB of RAM and a Intel Xeon E5520

Comment: What size is the motherboard? I can't seem to find info on that as well.

Comment: @JMY1000 Nor can I, I don't think its any normal kind of motherboard that has a specific name.

Comment: Can you measure it with a ruler or something of the sort? Maybe also mounting hole placement?

Comment: When I get the chance later on today I will try to take the mother board out any measure it and get a few photos of it

Comment: As far as I can tell, it uses a custom motherboard.  You probably won't be able to find an upgrade.

Comment: @Mark It's possible that with some coercion a standard motherboard could be made to fit. Pretty hard to tell though without knowing what the dimensions are.